ADC MCP3564 doesn't work with external clock
I'm using the ADC MCP3564 (from Microchip) to sample and convert data from a triaxial accelerometer. Everything works correctly if I use the internal oscillator, but if I use an external oscillator (8 MHz) on the MCLK pin I don't get interrupts when data are converted (so ADC is not working).
From the scope I can see that interrupt signal and clock signal are at the same frequency and I can't understand why.
Thanks for your help,
Riccardo
